# Problem Setting up Security Rules in FIrestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I don't know why my security rules aren't working. It would be really helpful if someone can find the problem in this.

I want the user who sent a message in the chat be the only person able to edit or delete it. And the users present in the `blocked` `array` in the Chats document not be able to send any messages.

This is what i did:

```
    match /{document=**}{

        allow read, write : if false;
    }

    match /Chats/{ChatID}{
        allow read, write : if request.auth != null;
    }
    
    match /Chats/{ChatID}/Messages/{MessageID} {
        allow delete : if false;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    
    match /Chats/{ChatID}/Messages/{MessageID}{
        allow delete, update : if resource.data.sender == request.auth.uid;
      allow create : if !(request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Chats/$(ChatID)).data.blocked);
    }
```

Both of them doesn't seem to work. Anyone is able to delete the message and also the user is never able to send the message whether or not it's uid is present in the blockList.

**UPDATE:**
This is the document I am trying to delete.
[image: Document I am trying to delete]
This is the code i use to delete the document:

```java
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Chats").document(CHAT_ID).collection("Messages").document(MSG_ID).delete();
```

Comment: Do you have the user id in `resource.data.sender`?

Comment: yess @RafaelJan

Comment: OK, I can help you but I need your attention. What do you mean by "the user is never able to send the message whether or not it's uid is present in the blockList"? The user really can't send any message? In addition, please edit the question with your entire rules, not only part of it

Comment: Yes that's correct. I am always returned with an Error Message saying `PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permission`. @RafaelJan

Comment: Can you please edit the question with your entire rules?

Comment: Ok I did @RafaelJan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238942/discussion-between-rafaeljan-and-user).

Comment: We're still missing quite some information here. Can you edit your question again to include: 1) a screenshot of a document you are trying to delete, but can't. 2) the minimal code that reproduces the problem. In that code be sure to show that the conditions of you rules are met, e.g. by logging the UID of the current user, and the ID of the document you are trying to delete.

Comment: I have update the question. Hope there are all the information you asked for. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't create messages is:

`allow create : if !(request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Chats/$(ChatID)).data.blocked);`

please change it to this:

`allow create: if (request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Chats/$(ChatID)).data.blocked) == false;`

The reason anyone can delete is:

`allow delete, update : if resource.data.sender == request.auth.uid;`

please change it to this:

`allow delete, update : if (resource.data.sender == request.auth.uid);`